# Oracle Apex: How I can change :APEX$ROW_STATUS to 'U' of all rows in Interactive Grid on load time?

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to fetch data from One Table by using SQL Query. Now I want to modify some values in loaded rows. Some rows are not modified but I want to store All rows in another table. For this purpose I need :APEX$ROW_STATUS to 'U' for all rows. Please guide me how I can change :APEX$ROW_STATUS to 'U' of all rows without click one by one.

Comment: Do you need 'U' for modified rows, or for those who are not modified? I got confused.